# Mysql get latest row of self referencing relationship

Tags: mysql, innodb, self-referencing-table

I have a comments table and allow people to edit their comments.
Instead of overwriting comments I create a new comment and associate it to its "parent".
Additionally, I add the child information to the parent.

```
id, user_id, comment_id__parent, comment_id__child, comment, created_dt
```

**[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2457e0/1)**

Now my problem is that I would like to get all comments of a specific user but only the latest update of a comment.

This is giving me a huge headache for a while and I would appreciate very much your input!

Comment: What would the desired result set look like?

Comment: Sorry that i wasn't more specific but that's the expected result set: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2457e0/31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your fiddle is correct, you should be able to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM comments 
 WHERE comment_id__child IS NULL AND user_id=1;
```

This works if you always populate the `comment_id__child` for 'parent' comment when editing it.

Comment: are you forget Order By clause?

Comment: @RonakShah, `ORDER BY` isn't strictly necessary unless for returning the expected results. Of course it may be included, if needed.

Comment: he wants latest comments thats why you need to add order by created_dt desc

Comment: No, "I would like to get **all comments** of a specific user but only the **latest update**" hence the `ORDER BY` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

for uer_id =1

```
select * from comments where user_id=1 order by created_dt desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly! You can see the result in your sql fiddle.

```
select * from comments group by user_id having count(id) = 1
UNION
select * from comments where user_id in (select user_id from comments group by user_id having count(id) > 1) and comment_id__child is null and comment_id__parent is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
WHERE user_id = 1
  AND ( (comment_id__parent IS NULL
         AND comment_id__child IS NULL)
       OR (comment_id__parent IS NOT NULL
           AND comment_id__child IS NULL) )
ORDER BY created_dt DESC
```

Comment: This would only work for the user id 1. If you need to see the results for all users, you can check my comment. It works perfectly.